# Eigenvalues of a $12 \times 12$ Jacobian matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-system, jacobian

Consider the set of coordinates $X_{i, j}^{(\ell)}$ and $Y_{i, j}^{(\ell)}$, where $i \in (1, 2, 3), j \in (1, 2, 3)$ and $i \neq j$ and $\ell = \pm 1$. The superscipt $(\ell)$ is an index. Consider the change of variables from $\mathbf{X}$ to $\mathbf{Y}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
Y_{i, j}^{(\ell)} = c_{i, j}^{(\ell)} + c_{i, k}^{(\ell)} X_{k, j}^{(\ell)} + c_{i, j}^{(-\ell)} X_{j, i}^{(-\ell)} X_{i, j}^{(\ell)} + c_{i, k}^{(-\ell)} X_{k, i}^{(-\ell)} X_{i, j}^{(\ell)} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $(i, j, k)$ is any permutation of $(1, 2, 3)$ and the $c_{i, j}^{(\ell)}$ are any non-zero numbers constrained, for each $i$, by $c_{i, j}^{(1)} + c_{i, k}^{(1)} + c_{i, j}^{(-1)} + c_{i, k}^{(-1)} = K$ for some constant $K > 0$. So, for example, if $i = 1$ then $c_{1, 2}^{(1)} + c_{1, 3}^{(1)} + c_{1, 2}^{(-1)} + c_{1, 3}^{(-1)} = K$.

Let $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{X})= \partial \mathbf{Y}/ \partial \mathbf{X}$ be the Jacobian matrix of the transformation in Eq. $(1)$. Let $\mathbf{1}$ be a vector of length $12$ consisting of all $1$'s.

> **Fact 1**: The constant $K$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{1})$.
>
> **Fact 2**: If there is a vector $\mathbf{v}$ satisfying $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{1}) \mathbf{v} = K \mathbf{v}$, then it has the property that $v_{i, j}^{(k)} + v_{j, i}^{(k)} = 0$, where $v_{a, b}^{(c)}$ is the entry of $\mathbf{v}$ corresponding to coordinate $X_{a, b}^{(c)}$.

I know Fact 1 and Fact 2 are facts, because the eigensystem of a $12 \times 12$ matrix is still (barely) within the realm of tractability for computers. My question is therefore:

> Is there any way to see that either Fact 1 or Fact 2 is true without having to actually find the eigenvector?

A relevant, similar question I have asked is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254688/eigenvalues-of-the-jacobian-matrix-of-a-quadratic-change-of-variables). In that case, it was "easy" to guess the eigenvector but I can't see how to do that here. It has to be something about the structure of Eq. $(1)$. There's this idea that if the sum of the coefficients of a transformation is constrained to be a constant in the way I've described, then this constraint shows up as an eigenvalue of the Jacobian and I wonder how general this property is.

**Mathematica Code**

Using the convention $c_{i, j}^{(\ell)} = c[i, j, \ell]$, the Jacobian is

```
jac = {{c[1, 2, 1] + c[1, 3, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, c[1, 2, 1], 0, 0, 0, c[1, 3, 1], c[1, 3, -1], 0},
{0, c[1, 2, -1] + c[1, 3, -1], 0, 0, c[1, 2, -1], 0, 0, 0, c[1, 3, -1], 0, 0, c[1, 3, 1]},
{0, 0, c[1, 2, 1] + c[1, 3, 1], 0, 0, c[1, 2, 1], c[1, 2, -1], 0, 0, c[1, 3, 1], 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, c[1, 2, -1] + c[1, 3, -1], c[1, 2, -1], 0, 0, c[1, 2, 1], c[1, 3, -1], 0, 0, 0},
{0, c[2, 1, 1], 0, 0, c[2, 1, 1] + c[2, 3, 1], 0, 0, 0, c[2, 3, -1], 0, 0, c[2, 3, 1]},
{c[2, 1, -1], 0, 0, 0, 0, c[2, 1, -1] + c[2, 3, -1], 0, 0, 0, c[2, 3, 1], c[2, 3, -1], 0},
{0, c[2, 1, 1], c[2, 1, -1], 0, 0, 0, c[2, 1, 1] + c[2, 3, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, c[2, 3, 1]},
{c[2, 1, -1], 0, 0, c[2, 1, 1], 0, 0, 0, c[2, 1, -1] + c[2, 3, -1], 0, 0, c[2, 3, -1], 0},
{0, 0, 0, c[3, 1, 1], c[3, 2, -1], 0, 0, c[3, 2, 1], c[3, 1, 1] + c[3, 2, 1], 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, c[3, 1, -1], 0, 0, c[3, 2, 1], c[3, 2, -1], 0, 0, c[3, 1, -1] + c[3, 2, -1], 0, 0},
{c[3, 1, -1], 0, 0, c[3, 1, 1], 0, 0, 0, c[3, 2, 1], 0, 0, c[3, 1, 1] + c[3, 2, 1], 0},
{0, c[3, 1, 1], c[3, 1, -1], 0, 0, 0, c[3, 2, -1], 0, 0, 0, 0, c[3, 1, -1] + c[3, 2, -1]}}
```

Where the rows are in the order

```
rows = {c[1, 2, -1], c[1, 2, 1], c[1, 3, -1], c[1, 3, 1], c[2, 1, -1], c[2, 1, 1],
      c[2, 3, -1], c[2, 3, 1], c[3, 1, -1], c[3, 1, 1], c[3, 2, -1], c[3, 2, 1]}
```

Here's a sample set of $c_{i,j}^{(\ell)}$ where $K = 1$:

```
vec = {0.213509, -0.0587312, 0.321703, 0.523519, 0.255562, -0.290697,
     0.211956, 0.823179, 0.0321628, 1.087800, -0.373663, 0.253700}
```

Running the following command:

```
Eigenvalues[jac /. Thread[rows -> vec]]
```

Shows that $1$ is indeed an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\mathbf{J(1)}\color{red}{-KI_{12}}$ and
\begin{aligned}
v&=(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{12})^T\\
&=\left(v_{1,2}^{(-1)},\ v_{1,2}^{(1)},\ v_{1,3}^{(-1)},\ v_{1,3}^{(1)},\ v_{2,1}^{(-1)},\ v_{2,1}^{(1)},\ v_{2,3}^{(-1)},\ v_{2,3}^{(1)},\ v_{3,1}^{(-1)},\ v_{3,1}^{(1)},\ v_{3,2}^{(-1)},\ v_{3,2}^{(1)},\ \right)^T.
\end{aligned}
Then $\mathbf{J(1)}v=Kv$ if and only if $Mv=0$.

Numerical experiments suggest that the nullspace of $M$ contains vectors $v$ with
$$
v_1=-v_5,\quad v_2=-v_6,\quad v_3=-v_9,\quad v_4=-v_{10},\quad v_7=-v_{11},\quad v_8=-v_{12}.
$$
Therefore, to prove both fact 1 and fact 2, it suffices to show that the following $12\times6$ matrix is *not* of full column rank:
$$
P=\pmatrix{m_{\ast1}-m_{\ast5}&m_{\ast2}-m_{\ast6}&m_{\ast3}-m_{\ast9}&m_{\ast4}-m_{\ast10}&m_{\ast7}-m_{\ast11}&m_{\ast8}-m_{\ast12}}.\tag{1}
$$
Using the value of $\mathbf{J(1)}$ given by your Mathematica output, we obtain
$$
P=\pmatrix{
-x_3-x_4  &-x_1      &0        &-x_2     &-x_4     &0\\
-x_3      &-x_1-x_2  &-x_4     &0        &0        &-x_2\\
0         &-x_1      &-x_3-x_4 &-x_2     &x_3      &0\\
-x_3      &0         &-x_4     &-x_1-x_2 &0        &x_1\\
x_7+x_8   &x_6       &-x_7     &0        &0        &-x_5\\
x_8       &x_5+x_6   &0        &-x_5     &-x_7     &0\\
0         &x_6       &x_8      &0        &-x_7-x_8 &-x_5\\
x_8       &0         &0        &x_6      &-x_7     &-x_5-x_6\\
-x_{12}   &0         &x_{11}+x_{12}  &x_9      &0        &x_{10}\\
0         &-x_{10}   &x_{11}   &x_9+x_{10}&x_{12}      &0\\
x_{11}    &0         &0        &x_9      &x_{11}+x_{12}  &x_{10}\\
0         &x_9       &x_{11}   &0        &x_{12}      &x_9+x_{10}}
$$
where the $x_n$s are shorthands for the $X_{i,j}^{(\ell)}$s:
$$
\pmatrix{
x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4\\
x_5&x_6&x_7&x_8\\
x_9&x_{10}&x_{11}&x_{12}}
=\pmatrix{
X_{1,2}^{(-1)} &X_{1,2}^{(1)} &X_{1,3}^{(-1)} &X_{1,3}^{(1)}\\
X_{2,1}^{(-1)} &X_{2,1}^{(1)} &X_{2,3}^{(-1)} &X_{2,3}^{(1)}\\
X_{3,1}^{(-1)} &X_{3,1}^{(1)} &X_{3,2}^{(-1)} &X_{3,2}^{(1)}}.
$$
Now perform the following column operations on $P$:
$$
C1\leftarrow C1-C5,\quad C2\leftarrow C2-C6,\quad  C3\leftarrow C3+C5,\quad  C4\leftarrow C4+C6.\tag{2}
$$
The submatrix containing the first four columns of matrix $P$ then becomes:
$$
Q=\pmatrix{
-x_3     &-x_1     &-x_4    &-x_2   \\
-x_3     &-x_1     &-x_4    &-x_2   \\
-x_3     &-x_1     &-x_4    &-x_2   \\
-x_3     &-x_1     &-x_4    &-x_2   \\
x_7+x_8  &x_5+x_6  &-x_7    &-x_5   \\
x_7+x_8  &x_5+x_6  &-x_7    &-x_5   \\
x_7+x_8  &x_5+x_6  &-x_7    &-x_5   \\
x_7+x_8  &x_5+x_6  &-x_7    &-x_5   \\
-x_{12}     &-x_{10}   &x_{11}+x_{12} &x_9+x_{10}\\
-x_{12}     &-x_{10}   &x_{11}+x_{12} &x_9+x_{10}\\
-x_{12}     &-x_{10}   &x_{11}+x_{12} &x_9+x_{10}\\
-x_{12}     &-x_{10}   &x_{11}+x_{12} &x_9+x_{10}}.
$$
Since the row rank of $Q$ is $\le3$, $Q$ has not full column rank. Thus $Q(x,y,z,w)^T=0$ for some $(x,y,z,w)\ne0$. By $(2)$, this means $Pu=0$ when
$$
u=x(e_1'-e_5')+y(e_2'-e_6')+z(e_3'+e_5')+w(e_4'+e_6')
=(x,\ y,\ z,\ w,\ z-x,\ w-y)^T
$$
where $\{e_1',e_2',\ldots,e_6'\}$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb R^6$. In turn, by $(1)$, we have $Mv=0$ (or equivalently, $\mathbf{J(1)}v=Kv$) when
\begin{aligned}
v&=\left(v_{1,2}^{(-1)},\ v_{1,2}^{(1)},\ v_{1,3}^{(-1)},\ v_{1,3}^{(1)},\ v_{2,1}^{(-1)},\ v_{2,1}^{(1)},\ v_{2,3}^{(-1)},\ v_{2,3}^{(1)},\ v_{3,1}^{(-1)},\ v_{3,1}^{(1)},\ v_{3,2}^{(-1)},\ v_{3,2}^{(1)}\right)^T\\
&=u_1(e_1-e_5)+u_2(e_2-e_6)+u_3(e_3-e_9)+u_4(e_4-e_{10})+u_5(e_7-e_{11})+u_6(e_8-e_{12})\\
&=(x,\ y,\ z,\ w,\ -x,\ -y,\ z-x,\ w-y,\ -z,\ -w,\ x-z,\ y-w)^T.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Is there any underlying reason for the column operations? I noticed recently that the eigenvector also has the property that
$$
\begin{align}
v_{1, 3}^{(1)} &= v_{1, 2}^{(1)} + v_{2, 3}^{(1)} \\ 
v_{1, 3}^{(-1)} &= v_{1, 2}^{(-1)} + v_{2, 3}^{(-1)} \\ 
v_{3, 1}^{(1)} &= v_{3, 2}^{(1)} + v_{2, 1}^{(1)} \\ 
v_{3, 1}^{(-1)} &= v_{3, 2}^{(-1)} + v_{2, 1}^{(-1)}
\end{align}
$$ 
Is it related?

Comment: @Mr.G You can get this by back-substituting the solution $r$ of $Qr=0$ into the solution $u$ of $Pu=0$ and then by back-substituting $u$ into the solution $v$ of $Mv=0$. See my new edit.